# Copy textbox in popup to a 3rd level subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I am trying to copy data from a textbox of a popup form to the textbox of a 3rd level subform. The code works when I open the popup from the parent but not when nested, as intended.

```
If (Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtAmount_Total.Value = 0) Then
    Call cmdCancel_Click
Else
    Forms!frmEnter!txtFeeCount.Value = Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtCount_Total.Value
    Forms!frmEnter!txtFeeAmount.Value = Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtAmount_Total.Value
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmFeeEntry"
End If
```

Hierarchy: frmEnter subform of navMain subform of navRoot. frmFeeEntry is a popup only available in frmEnter.

I have searched for days to find the right combination to make this work. I tried variations of the following:

```
Forms!navRoot!navMain.Form!frmEnter!txtFeeCount.Value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When referencing subforms, must reference the subform container control. If the container has default name assigned by Access, probably like: `Forms!navRoot.NavigationSubform.Form.txtFeeCount`. But that only goes to a 2nd level form.

Comment: You are correct! This does work if I run from the 2nd level: `Forms!navMain.NavigationSubform.Form.txtFeeCount`

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

If i where you i would work with an additonal table where you save the value from txtFeeCount, or any other value. Then when you need the value from the subform you can get it there...

Good luck.

[image: Example]

Comment: That maybe the way I will need to do it. Just hoping I can work out a direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

The key was to name the two Navigation Subforms to allow the db to differentiate.

```
If (Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtAmount_Total.Value = 0) Then
    Call cmdCancel_Click
Else
    Forms!navRoot!navsubRoot.Form!navsubMain.Form.txtFeeCount.Value = Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtCount_Total.Value
    Forms!navRoot!navsubRoot.Form!navsubMain.Form.txtFeeAmount.Value = Forms!frmFeeEntry!txtAmount_Total.Value
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmFeeEntry"
End If
```